# disable horizontal scrolling on webpage on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm trying to disable horizontal scrolling on my website without success. I read somewhere that this would do the job:

```
<head>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    </script>
<head>
```

I don't know javascript very well so I don't know if it's supposed to work.

I have set the viewport like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-widht, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

I can still scroll horizontally on my iPhone so that the webpage leaves the screen and shows the "default safari background".

What's wrong or missing?

Comment: Side note, check your spelling; `widht=device-widht`

Comment: why not set overflow-x to hidden using css?